# Add single quote in beginning and end of JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I have a JSON object :

```
{"status":"true","result":{
"1":{"nim":"001","nama":"LEROY","prodi":"MI","jurusan":"TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI","id_kelas":"1"},
"2":{"nim":"002","nama":"JENKINS","prodi":"MI","jurusan":"TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI","id_kelas":"1"}},
"message":"Data Berhasil Ditambahkan"}
```

I wanted to add a single quote (') in the beginning and the end of JSON Object. So it will be like :

```
'{"status":"true","result":{
"1":{"nim":"001","nama":"LEROY","prodi":"MI","jurusan":"TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI","id_kelas":"1"},
"2":{"nim":"002","nama":"JENKINS","prodi":"MI","jurusan":"TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI","id_kelas":"1"}},
"message":"Data Berhasil Ditambahkan"}'
```

I've been trying of using the concat command :

```
"'".<json object above>."'"
```

But it appears that it wasn't the one I needed because it resulted in different type (string) of object.

Anyway, I need help with this, and any help will greatly appreciated!

Comment: Putting quotes round it will stop it being JSON and make it into a string (as you have experienced), why do you want to do this? You need to give us a bit more context.

Comment: I wanted to use the stringified json to json_decode, to get its array form. But when I use the manual qoutes, it shows "Array to string conversion" error/notice.

Answer (score 0):

Umm... it Just Works for me.  I copy/paste your original string to a file (saves as "/home/me/jo")

```
{"status":"true","result":{
"1":{"nim":"001","nama":"LEROY","prodi":"MI","jurusan":"TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI","id_kelas":"1"},
"2":{"nim":"002","nama":"JENKINS","prodi":"MI","jurusan":"TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI","id_kelas":"1"}},
"message":"Data Berhasil Ditambahkan"}
```

Then

```
<?php

$json=file_get_contents("jo");

$json_object=json_decode($json);

print_r($json_object);

?>
```

Gives me

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => true
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nim] => 001
                    [nama] => LEROY
                    [prodi] => MI
                    [jurusan] => TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI
                    [id_kelas] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nim] => 002
                    [nama] => JENKINS
                    [prodi] => MI
                    [jurusan] => TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI
                    [id_kelas] => 1
                )

        )

    [message] => Data Berhasil Ditambahkan
)
```

So what exactly is the problem?